# Will my Wordpress site become vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) if I allow img tags in the comments area?

Tags: html, security

I'm planning to follow [this](http://theos.in/wordpress/howto-change-list-of-allowed-html-tags-in-wordpress/) tutorial in order to allow my subscribers to add images to comments (actually a custom post type called "Replies").

Wordpress filters `<img>` tags by default (except for the admin).

Will my Wordpress site be vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) if I allow img HTML tags in my comment section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many evil things can be done by including an image. The question is how well WordPress filters them. To give you an idea:

- [File names should be checked
  properly.](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070603/image-upload-xss/)
- [The actual image data can contain
  javascript.](http://www.databasesandlife.com/xss-attack-images/)
- [Also, EXIF data could contain
  javascript.](http://www.aloshbennett.in/weblog/2010/web-2-0/cross-site-scripting-through-image-exif/)

Comment: Does Wordpress have any special way of filtering them?